# C# lambda expression unable to manage a certain string compare

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a specific lambda what doesn't seem to want to work properly although the logic seems sound.

```
index = llCodeList.FindIndex(f => string.Compare(f.Threshold.ToString(), searchText, true ) >= 0);
```

f.Threshold is an integer value, it seems that the conversion doesn't happen and it breaks my search function.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: How does it break your search? Can you show the result of some sample input?

Comment: A short but complete program would really help. I really doubt that you've found a bug in the C# compiler or .NET...

Comment: your lambda evaluates to true if `f.Threshold` is lexicographically equal or greater than `searchText`. how do `f.Threshold` and `searchText` look like?

Comment: SO you're trying to find the index of the first element with a threshold greater or equal to a value supplied by the user? Is that correct? Would it not be better to try and convert the searchText to an int and then compare ints? Comparing the two strings is unlikely to give you the result you want.

Comment: he's seeing if the search text is a subset of the `f.Threshold` that's what `>= 0` means from `string.Compare` 0 == match, 1 == string a is greater than string b (not by numerical value)

Comment: Jimmy: `IndexOf` >= 0 != `Compare` >= 0, that's what this problem is about it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not ditch the string compare and explicitly check?

```
index = llCodeList.FindIndex(
            f => f.Threshold.ToString()
                            .Contains(searchText));
```

Are you sure that the search text is a subset of the threshold number?

Also it may be that you're not understanding how `string.Compare` works, it won't check numerical value but string value. For the above if `searchText` is `4` and the threshold is `-40` would match your predicate. My example more explicitly demonstrates the behavior of `string.Compare(...,...,...) >= 0`

If you're trying to find results based on having a greater than or equal to match on threshold and searchText you could do this

```
int search = 0;
int32.TryParse(searchText, out search);
index = llCodeList.FindIndex(f => f.Threshold >= search);
```

Answer (score 0):

If my comment correctly got the gist of what you are trying to do then do something like this:

```
int index = -1;
int intVal;
if (int.TryParse(seachText, intVal)){
  index = llCodeList.FindIndex(f => f.Threshold >= intVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to check `IndexOf` instead of using `Compare`.

```
index = llCodeList.FindIndex(
    f => f.Threshold.ToString().IndexOf(
        searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

But the name `FindIndex` sounds like you'd want to return the actual index. My crystal ball says you're looking for something like

```
index = llCodeList.FindIndex(
    f => f.Threshold.ToString().IndexOf(
        searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```